# Sum of positive infinity and negative infinity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, self-learning, infinity

Consider the following function of $\tau$:

$$
h(\tau) := C_1 \ln\left(1-\frac{a}{\tau}\right) - C_2 \ln\left(1-\frac{b}{\tau}\right),
$$

where $a > b>0$ and $C_2=\ln(1-b)<C_1=\ln(1-a)<0$. Then it is claimed that

$$
\lim_{\tau \to 0}h(\tau) = \infty.
$$

I do not understand why this is the case. As $\tau$ goes to $0$ from the left, we would have $-\infty+\infty$. Why is this equal to $\infty$, please?

Comment: $-\infty + \infty$ is not well defined and could equal different things under different conditions.  Here you have one term going to $-\infty$ but another term going to $\infty$ but going there "faster".  The positive limit "wins out".

Consider $[3n - 1n] = 3n + (-n)$ Here the 3n goes to $\infty$ but the -n goes to $-\infty$.  So where does the actual limit go?  Well, 3n - n = 2n and that goes to $\infty$.  We can think of it as the 3n goes to $\infty$ "faster" than the (-n) goes to $-\infty$.

Comment: You should probably indicate at what level you're studying. It appears that the concept of limits are not entirely clear to you. Your observation is correct though, that's why the concept of limits was introduced in the first place (to get round the problems with infinities).

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
h(\tau) := C_1 \ln\left(1-\frac{a}{\tau}\right) - C_2 \ln\left(1-\frac{b}{\tau}\right)=
\ln\frac{\left(1-\frac{a}{\tau}\right)^{C_1}}{\left(1-\frac{b}{\tau}\right)^{C_2}}=
\ln\frac{\left(\tau-{a}\right)^{C_1}}{\left(\tau-{b}\right)^{C_2}}\tau^{C_2-C_1}
\\=
\ln\frac{\left(\tau-{a}\right)^{C_1}}{\left(\tau-{b}\right)^{C_2}} + ({C_2-C_1})\ln\tau
\end{align}

can you take the limit now?